# Detalles del error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /> <b>"... is not valid JSON at parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buenas programadores del mundo, me gustaría que me ayudaran o aconsejarme en un problema que me muestra dentro de 000webhost, el problema es que yo realizo un proceso de solicitud es decir registrar, y utilizo este código:

```
 $("#formRegisSoliInsuFalto").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Obtener los valores del formulario
        var fechSoli = $.trim($("#fechSoli").val());
        var selecttipoIns = $.trim($('#selecttipoIns option:selected').text());
        var nom_insu = $.trim($("#nombre_insu").val());
        var Canti = $.trim($("#Canti").val());
        var id_usuario_empleado = $.trim($("#id_usuario_empleado").val());

        console.log("Fecha Solicitud:", fechSoli,
            "\nTipo de Insumo:", selecttipoIns,
            "\nNombre del Insumo:", nom_insu,
            "\nCantidad:", Canti,
            "\nID del Usuario Empleado:", id_usuario_empleado);



        // Enviar los datos mediante AJAX
        $.ajax({
             url: "../validacion_datos/validar_regis_solicitud_insu.php", // Reemplaza esto con la ruta de tu script de servidor que procesa el registro
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
                 fechSoli: fechSoli,
                 selecttipoIns: selecttipoIns,
                 nom_insu: nom_insu,
                 Canti: Canti,
                 id_usuario_empleado: id_usuario_empleado
             },
             success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response); 
                 if (response.status === 'success') {
                     Swal.fire({
                         icon: 'success',
                         title: 'Registro exitoso!',
                     }).then((result) => {
                         if (result.value) {
                             location.reload();
                         }
                     });
                 } else {
                     Swal.fire({
                         title: response.message,
                         icon: 'warning'
                     });
                 }
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error en la solicitud:", textStatus);
                    console.log("Detalles del error:", errorThrown); 
                 Swal.fire({
                     title: 'Error en la solicitud',
                     icon: 'error'
                 });
             }
         });
    });
```

y el php para poder realizaar la logica es esta:
el problema es que me sale error al enviar la información, error como el siguiente:

Comment: Este error es común, haces una solicitud y el servidor te devuelve una página en lugar de un JSON, esto generalmente sucede porque la ruta no es valida (error 404), o hay un error de código (error 500), también puede ser de permisos. Tienes que presionar F12 en el navegador e ir a la pestaña de "Red", luego ejecuta  tu solicitud y ahí tendrás la respuesta que te está arrojando el servidor

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué hay en tu archivo con nombre kilométrico `validar_regis_solicitud_insu.php`? Si no controlas las salidas en ese archivo emitiendo un JSON válido ocurrirá este error, porque Ajax está esperando como respuesta un JSON válido.